# I know my title view is a UISegmentedControl, Xcode still warns me

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UINavigationalController of which I've set the titleView to a UISegmentedControl.

Later on, if I do something like.

`[self.navigationItem.titleView setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];`

I get a warning saying that UIView may not respond to this message. Of course it does and works fine but how do I properly get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the titleView as a UISegmentedControl:

```
[(UISegmentedControl *)self.navigationItem.titleView 
                                           setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to DyingCactus's suggestion:

```
UISegmentedControl * segments = self.navigationItem.titleView;
[segments setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```